# Indicate when content changes on another tab

Tags: javascript, css

I have multiple tabs but I'd like to indicate when a change occurs on another tab that the user hasn't clicked. For instance, when the user hits the run button when they're on the Data pane I want to make the `Errors` tab change to red to indicate that there was also a change to that tab - how do I achieve this? (Conversely, if they're on the error tab, the Data tab should become red). Also once the tab is clicked on, I'd like to remove the red color. Any help appreciated!

## Desired Output

[image]

```js
runCode = () => {
   document.getElementById("dataOutput").innerHTML = "Paragraph changed!"
   document.getElementById("errorOutput").innerHTML = "Error Occured"
 }
```

```css
.fab {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #A7C0CD;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 58px;
  float: right;
  margin: 8px;
  z-index: 5000;
  position: absolute;
  right:0;
  top:0;
}

.fab:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  transform: scale(1.05);
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <head>
    <!-- Visual appearance -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.4.1/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap.min.js@3.3.5/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

<div class="fab" id="runCode" onclick="runCode();">RUN</div>
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
          <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#data">Data</a></li>
          <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#error">Errors</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div class="tab-content">
          <div id="data" class="tab-pane fade in active">
            <div id="dataOutput"></div>
          </div>
          <div id="error" class="tab-pane fade">
            <div id="errorOutput"></div>
          </div>
        </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: With JQuery: ````$("a[href='#error']").css("color", "red");````
With Pure JS: ````document.querySelectorAll("[href='#error']").style.color = "red";````
I do recommend giving your tab <li>'s id's or class names.

Comment: Thanks for the response - but what if the user is on the Error tab, then I'd want the Data tab to turn red...

Comment: ok I can adjust my answer for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I achieved what you want using `MutationObserver`s. It's fairly brittle and could use some refactoring, but you get the point I hope:

```js
// store a reference to our tabs as we're going to re-use them
const data = document.getElementById("dataOutput");
const error = document.getElementById("errorOutput");
const runCode = () => {
  data.textContent = "Paragraph changed!";
  error.textContent = "Error Occured";
};

// remove the 'changed' class from clicked tabs
const tabs = document.querySelector('.nav-tabs');
tabs.onclick = ({ target }) => target.classList.remove('changed');

// we're going to watch for mutations of our output-elements
new MutationObserver(observe).observe(data, { childList: true });
new MutationObserver(observe).observe(error, { childList: true })

function observe(mutations) {
  const target = mutations[0].target;
  // get the name of the changed tab by slicing of 'Output' from the target's id
  const tabName = target.id.slice(0, target.id.indexOf('O'));
  const tab = document.querySelector(`a[href="#${tabName}"]`);
 
  // give the 'changed' class to the tab related to the changed dom-node,
  // if it's not currently active
  if (!target.parentNode.classList.contains('active')) {
    tab.classList.add('changed');
  }
}
```

```css
.fab {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #A7C0CD;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 58px;
  float: right;
  margin: 8px;
  z-index: 5000;
  position: absolute;
  right:0;
  top:0;
}

.fab:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  transform: scale(1.05);
}

a.changed {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <head>
    <!-- Visual appearance -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.4.1/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap.min.js@3.3.5/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

<div class="fab" id="runCode" onclick="runCode();">RUN</div>
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
          <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#data">Data</a></li>
          <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#error">Errors</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div class="tab-content">
          <div id="data" class="tab-pane fade in active">
            <div id="dataOutput"></div>
          </div>
          <div id="error" class="tab-pane fade">
            <div id="errorOutput"></div>
          </div>
        </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

An example of how to do this:

```js
runCode = () => {
   document.getElementById("dataOutput").innerHTML = "Paragraph changed!"
   document.getElementById("errorOutput").innerHTML = "Error Occured"
   document.querySelector("li:not(.active) > a").style.color = "Red"
 }
```

```css
.fab {
      width: 60px;
      height: 60px;
      background-color: #A7C0CD;
      border-radius: 50%;
      box-shadow: 0px 3px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
      transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
      font-size: 15px;
      font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
      line-height: 58px;
      float: right;
      margin: 8px;
      z-index: 5000;
      position: absolute;
      right:0;
      top:0;
    }

    .fab:hover {
      box-shadow: 0px 3px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
      transform: scale(1.05);
    }
```

```html
 <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      </head>
        <!-- Visual appearance -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.4.1/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap.min.js@3.3.5/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      </head>
      <body>

    <div class="fab" id="runCode" onclick="runCode();">RUN</div>
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
              <li class="active"><a id="dataTab" data-toggle="tab" href="#data">Data</a></li>
              <li><a id="errorTab" data-toggle="tab" href="#error">Errors</a></li>
            </ul>

            <div class="tab-content">
              <div id="data" class="tab-pane fade in active">
                <div id="dataOutput"></div>
              </div>
              <div id="error" class="tab-pane fade">
                <div id="errorOutput"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Now for a more dynamic solution. You can have Javascript detect the text outputted in one of the tabs and find it's corresponding tab switch on the top and turn that red.

All I did was give the tabs an id and change the css property of "color".

Comment: Thanks for your input, I don't want to hard code the error tab as red because what if the user is navigated to the error tab, then I'd want the Data tab to turn red - does that make sense?

Comment: How does this seem, if you run it on either tab, the other one becomes red